# Is suppress warning option removed in new version of Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

[image]

In older versions, there was an arrow after the "Rename" option, and we can choose to add suppress warning annotation.

But when I updated the IDE, it was gone. Is this feature removed and we should add suppress annotation manually?